# Batch merge/mux .srt from multiple languages with .mkv files

Tags: batch

My use case is nearly the same than [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1035553/batch-merge-mux-srt-with-mkv-files) except I have 2 subtitles tracks:

TVShow - Episode 01.mkv

TVShow - Episode 01.FR.srt

TVShow - Episode 01.EN.srt

TVShow - Episode 02.mkv

TVShow - Episode 02.FR.srt

TVShow - Episode 02.EN.srt

I'd like to merge both subtitles tracks (with the right subtitle label when opening the merged mkv).

The working mkvmerge line for a single video file is:

```
"C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" --ui-language fr --output ^"C:\Temp\test\TVShow - Episode 01 ^(1^).mkv^" --no-subtitles --language 0:eng --language 1:eng --default-track 1:yes ^"^(^" ^"C:\Temp\test\TVShow - Episode 01.mkv^" ^"^)^" --language 0:eng ^"^(^" ^"C:\Temp\test\TVShow - Episode 01.EN.srt^" ^"^)^" --language 0:fre ^"^(^" ^"C:\Temp\test\TVShow - Episode 01.FR.srt^" ^"^)^" --track-order 0:0,0:1,1:0,2:0
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For this question I would use the code below based on the conversation that was linked (make sure to save this as .bat not .txt).

```
for %%A IN (*.mkv) do (
"C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "remux-%%~nxA" "%%~A" --track-name "0:English" --language "0:eng" "%%~nA.EN.srt" --track-name "0:French" --language "0:fre" "%%~nA.FR.srt"
pause
)
```

If you want this to be completely automated, remove the `pause` line.