# How to Batch Merge Identically-Named Subtitles and Audio Files Into a .MKV File

Tags: audio, subtitles, matroska

I am very unfamiliar with how batch processing with MKVToolNix (I just barely know how to save a .bat file and make it use MKVToolNix), so forgive me if this is obvious. I found an answer here ([Batch merge/mux .srt with .mkv files](https://superuser.com/questions/1035553/batch-merge-mux-srt-with-mkv-files)) as to how I could batch merge subtitles (.ASS, SSA, and .SRT I just have to change the extension name in the code) into their respective .MKV or files with this code:

```
for %%A IN (*.mkv) do ( "B:\OneDrive\Portable applications\mkvtoolnix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "remux-%%~nxA" "%%~A" --forced-track "0:yes" --default-track "0:yes" --track-name "0:English" --language "0:eng" "%%~nA.srt" )
```

This will create a single remuxed .MKV file per episode like this:

- Episode 1.mkv
- Episode 1.srt
- Episode 2.mkv
- Episode 2.srt

To

- Episode 1.mkv (with the .srt file)
- Episode 2.mkv (with the .srt file)

Etc.

But how would one go about also incorporating audio, say a structure like this:

- Episode 1.flac
- Episode 1.mkv
- Episode 1.srt
- Episode 2.flac
- Episode 2.mkv
- Episode 2.srt

To

- Episode 1.mkv (with the .srt and .flac file)
- Episode 2.mkv (with the .srt and .flac file)

And lastly, if I were to add an extra subtitle language like say Spanish. How difficult would this be to manage, like:

- Episode 1.flac
- Episode 1.mkv
- Episode 1 (En).srt
- Episode 1 (Spa).srt
- Episode 2.flac
- Episode 2.mkv
- Episode 2 (En).srt
- Episode 2 (Spa).srt

Comment: Please learn more about mkvmerge first:https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html, also you should consider doing this in PowerShell:https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell, and the code you posted won't work if you don't have the executable at the path(which I doubt), and the meaning of the variables: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html